# Is there a verb for "is an alternative to"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Two things that are similar, or alike, can be said to "resemble" each other:

> A is similar to B, A is like B <==> A resembles B.

In that thinking, what can I say if things are not only similar, but can be used interchangeably:

> A is an alternative to B, A can be used instead of B <==> **???**

I was thinking about "can replace", but I wonder if there is a single word that conveyes both meanings ("replacement", but also "optionality", if that is a word).

Answer (score 1):

A "substitutes" B

SUBSTITUTE : to use in place of something else with the same function.

- I had no shallots so I substituted onion.

Comment: Your example is slightly off because you use a different subject ("I"). Still, I like "substitute". Is there a difference between "A substitutes B" and "A substitutes for B"?

Comment: It's completely off.  'To use in place of something else with the same function.' doesn't mean 'to be an acceptable alternative for'. 'Onions substitute shallots' is unidiomatic.